# WebView in Fragment Back button kills my app when pressed

Tags: android, jquery, webview, fragment

im developent a wiki for an online game and everything works well on my app but there is a little big porblem, when i press back button app got killed.

My app have Navigation drawer with fragment, when a menu is pressed it loads a fragment and instantly a webview, in the web view im using Jquery webpage generated by DreamWeaver, everything is fine, but when user press BACK button i want the Fragment to be reloaded (back to the selected menu)

Example-> Open menu-> clicked "heroes" -> Fragment loaded -> Webview loaded -> HTML Menu displayed-> User press Backbutton -> Fragment reload -> Web view loaded -> HTML menu loaded.

i dont know if im giving you a good example, excuse me, and thank your for reading this.

Fragment code:

```
public class HeroesFragment extends Fragment {

    public HeroesFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.heroes, container, false);
        WebView heroespage = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.heroeswiki);
        WebSettings webSettings = heroespage.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        heroespage.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/heroes/index.html");

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

i tried several solution with no sucess like this:

```
public void onBackPressed () {
    if(wb != null) {
        if(wb.canGoBack()) {
             wb.goBack();
        } else {
             setContentView(R.layout.main);
             wb = null;
        }
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

this solutiongivme error on super.onBackPressed and or @Override givme some error too.

Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in Fragment, You'll not get OnBackPressed Overridden
Simpler way is to use below code

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(wb.canGoBack()) {
                    wb.goBack();
               } else {
                  setContentView(R.layout.main);
                  wb = null;
               }                
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: i got this error "Error:(43, 25) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)" and the same with the onKeyDown ;(, i pasted the code that you give me below    return rootView; after closing "}"

Comment: @EdgarGonzalez paste my code like     return rootView;
    } //paste my code here }

Comment: Please i still have problems, i uploaded the code to Pastebin with the current mods, also an Screenshot. Thanks for your time http://pastebin.com/itqUmF2Y http://s18.postimg.org/ysk64wknd/Untitled.png

Comment: @EdgarGonzalez, please contact me over email at bhavikmehta5491@gmail.com, so i can help you to fix this code, its long to answer here

Answer (score 0):

@Bhavik could you give here that long answer, because I stuck with this and can't fix it. I also got errors on setContentView and on super.onKeyDown...
Also I have problem with that onKeyDown, Android Studio says it isn't need to Override ?!? Something wrong with my Android Studio or what?